# How do I convert my code that transforms nested lists to a dataframe into a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists

I have 18 lists, one for each condition. Inside a list of a condiction there are 10 lists, one for each participant. Within a list of a participant, there is a list with anywhere between 1 and 20 values of type double. To clarify, this is code to reproduce the list of one condition, remember I have 18 of these all slightly different.

```
Participant_List <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  Scores <- list()
  for (k in sample(1:5, replace = TRUE)) {
    Scores[[k]] <- sample(1:7, sample(1:10), replace = TRUE)
  }
  Participant_List[[i]] <- Scores

}
```

Now with some help, I got code to transform the list of one condition into a data frame in a long format:

```
#convert each participant's list to a data frame
x_dataframes <- lapply(seq_along(Participant_List), function(curParticipant){
  return(data.frame(Participant = curParticipant,
                    Score = unlist(Participant_List[[curParticipant]])))
})

#combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe
x_combined <- do.call("rbind", x_dataframes)
```

I would like to create a function containing this code to be able to simply apply this to the other conditions. I came up with the following, where I first create a list containing the conditions I have, called  `Hypo1_lists`  and then I feed this into the function below:

```
function(Hypo1_lists){
  
  #convert each participant's list to a data frame
  x_dataframe <- lapply(seq_along(Hypo1_lists), function(curParticipant){
    return(data.frame(Participant = curParticipant,
                     Score = unlist(Hypo1_lists[[curParticipant]])))
    
  #combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe
  Hypo1_lists <- do.call("rbind", x_dataframe) 
})
  
}
```

But this outputs one nested list...I want to store the outputs in separate data frames (one for each condition), the same I get from the code before I put it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

You were mistakenly including the binding into the `apply` function.

```
myf <- function(Hypo1_lists){
  
  #convert each participant's list to a data frame
  x_dataframe <- lapply(seq_along(Hypo1_lists), function(curParticipant){
    return(data.frame(Participant = curParticipant,
                      Score = unlist(Hypo1_lists[[curParticipant]])))
  })
    #combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe
    Hypo1_lists <- do.call("rbind", x_dataframe) 

  return(Hypo1_lists)
}

myf(Participant_List)

    Participant Score
1             1     2
2             1     1
3             1     6
4             1     3
```

Also, don't forget to return something from your main function.

---

To apply this function to a nested list :

```
full <- list(Participant_List, Participant_List)
names(full) <- c("firstname", "secondname")
full_result <- lapply(full, myf)
summary(full_result)
           Length Class      Mode
firstname  2      data.frame list
secondname 2      data.frame list
```

To retrieve your second result for example, just use `full_result[[2]]` which is of class `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks! This already works well for a single list. What if I want to apply this function to multiple lists in one go? I assume I store the lists in a list and use lapply, but how do I make sure the result of each list is stored separately and named correctly?

Comment: you can indeed use lapply, then set the names. don't hesitate to create a new question and link it in these comments. In the meantime, if my answer is satisfactory, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Actually, this was my initial question of this post...how I loop the function I had over multiple lists of the different conditions. Your code provides a good answer when used on one list.

Comment: included in the answer, see edit

Comment: Many thanks! So for apply to work properly on a list I need the elements in a list to have a name?